# Trouble updating from Symfony 2.3 to 2.4

Tags: svn, symfony, composer-php

Hello I have a really serious and not logic trouble. I am trying to update my project from Symfony2.3 to the version 2.4, but after at the moment that I run the composer update is everything ok, but like the project is with more people and is on a SVN server when someone more download the project this doesnt work and at the moment that he ran composer update, this back to 2.3.*;

here is my composer.json:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"": "src/"}
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.4.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "cedriclombardot/admingenerator-generator-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
    "propel/propel-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "educoder/pest": "1.0.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.12.0",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "dev-master",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
    "phpexcel/phpexcel": "1.7.*",
    "laurentbrieu/tcpdf": "dev-master"

},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "component-dir": "web/components"

},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you committed your `composer.json` and `composer.lock`? And have the others updated their SVN checkouts and run `php composer.phar install`?

Comment: Well yes I did commit the composer.json and composer.lock, They did updated all the project and they dind't do php composer.phar install because when i uploaded i upload too the vendor file and all the libraries.

Comment: You have said _"when someone more download the project this doesnt work"_, but what exactly doesn't work? Do you get any error message?

Comment: The bootstrap.php.cache doesnt work. I solved this using exactly Symfony 2.4.1, We were using Symfony 2.4.2-DEV, I dont know i suppose there is a bug on this version yet.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using exactly Symfony 2.4.1, We were using Symfony 2.4.2-DEV, I dont know i suppose there is a bug on this version yet.